# Order statistic distances as a function of moments?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable defined over $0-1$ and let $X_1 . . . X_4$ be the order statistics of $4$ draws from $X$ (where $X_1$ is the minimum).

I am looking to see if I can identify any general conditions for $X$ such that
$$\mathbb{E(}X_4 - X_3) < 3\mathbb{E}(X_2 -X_1)$$

Intuitively, the validity of the inequality seems like it would be a property of the skewness of $X$. 
For example, in response to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57330/how-to-prove-an-inequality-involving-averages-of-different-order-statistics) (where the inequality in the first part of that question reduces to the one presented here) Sasha showed that the inequality holds for the Beta distribution(a,2) when $a \ > 0.512761$. As $\beta$ increases, I believe the critical value of $a$ increases (for example, when $\beta = 3$, $a > .6017$) but I believe in all cases the distribution has to be extremely positively skewed for it not to hold.  However, skewness alone can't be the only factor, as $Skew(Be(.512761,2)) = 1.21989$ and $Skew(Be(.6017,3)) = 1.3617$.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am looking for some way to say "the inequality holds so long as $X$ has _________ properties."

Comment: You might be interested in [L-moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-moment), which are defined in terms of expectations of order statistics. One can construct measures of skewness, kurtosis and scale out of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us start with an elementary remark: for every real numbers $u\le v$, 
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [u\le x\le v]\,\text{d}x=v-u.
$$
Thus, for every random variables $U$ and $V$ such that $U\le V$ almost surely,
integrating this with respect to the distribution of $(U,V)$ yields
$$
E(V-U)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} P(U\le x\le V)\,\text{d}x.
$$
Coming to the OP's question, we first note that the event $[X_1\le x\le X_2]$ is realized if and only if exactly one value from the sample is smaller than $x$ (and the other three are greater than $x$). Thus,
$$
P(X_1\le x\le X_2)=4F(x)(1-F(x))^3.
$$
Likewise, the event $[X_3\le x\le X_4]$ is realized if and only if exactly one value from the sample is greater than $x$ (and the other three are smaller than $x$). Thus,
$$
P(X_3\le x\le X_4)=4(1-F(x))F(x)^3.
$$ 
One sees that, for every positive $a$, $E(X_4-X_3)<aE(X_2-X_1)$ if and only if
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(x)(1-F(x))(a(1-F(x))^2-F^2(x))\,\text{d}x>0.
$$
For $a=3$, the condition reads
$
\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(1-F)(3-6F+2F^2)>0.
$

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome (thrice).